# Server Error in '/FH/FileHold/WebClient' Application

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

After trying to create another website in windows server 2016. The Existing FileHold WebClient Application throws an errors. One more thing is I can no longer locate the initial web.config file. This is the error I'm seeing.

The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.]
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) +240472
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +267
FileHold.WebClient.SessionManagerService.SessionManager.GetLogonAndPasswordSecuritySettings() in c:\Builds\5\FH\FileHold16.2.2\src\FileHold\WebClient\Web References\SessionManagerService\Reference.cs:747
FileHold.WebClient.LoginForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Builds\5\FH\FileHold16.2.2\src\FileHold\WebClient\LoginForm.aspx.cs:100
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdtd4.jpg)

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: Still the same error output

Comment: Is the error message in the xml file you generated using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) the same as what you posted? Can you post screenshots?